Baking only gives a black image
I have a model in blender that i added a material, but when i try to bake this material using the diffuse method, if i use the direct and color options it gives me a black image. If i select the color it will give me a solid color. I wanted to bake the texture so that i can export the model but im having a really hard time baking. I can never get it to work!



There are a lot of objects that are hidden only in the viewport. Or perhaps other objects are obstructing the light from reaching the intended object in the final render.
However, I conducted some tests, and below are the results along with their explanations.

I used the following settings :

Bake Type > Combined;
Influence > Direct;
Contributions > Diffuse/Glossy.


Hi Rafael, i made a new blender file with just one object and it doesn't work either way! it gives the same exact results
